# TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not list

Tags: python, datetime, utc

I am trying to plot the following data:

```
01/01/2012 01:00
01/01/2012 02:00
01/01/2012 03:00
01/01/2012 04:00
01/01/2012 05:00
01/01/2012 06:00
01/01/2012 07:00
01/01/2012 08:00
01/01/2012 09:00
01/01/2012 10:00
01/01/2012 11:00
01/01/2012 12:00
01/01/2012 13:00
01/01/2012 14:00
01/01/2012 15:00
01/01/2012 16:00
01/01/2012 17:00
01/01/2012 18:00
01/01/2012 19:00
01/01/2012 20:00
01/01/2012 21:00
01/01/2012 22:00
01/01/2012 23:00
02/01/2012 00:00
04/01/2012 23:00
................
05/01/2012 00:00
05/01/2012 01:00
................
```

Against wind_speed data which is in the format:

```
 [ 3.30049159  2.25226244  1.44078451 ... 12.8397099   9.75722427
  7.98525797]
```

My code is:

```
    T = T[1:]
    print( datetime.datetime.strptime(T, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S").strftime("%Y%m%d %I:%M:%S") #pharsing the time
    TIMESTAMP = [str (i) for i in T]
    plt.plot_date(TIMESTAMP, wind_speed)
    plt.show()
```

However, I am receiving the error message "TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str", not list. I am new to Python and would appreciate help on how to either convert to the list to a string or another method on how to resolve this. Thank you!

Comment: `T = T[1]`?.....

Comment: @Rakesh I am using T = T[1] to skip the first cell in the column

Comment: Do you want to convert all string datetime in list to datetime object?

Comment: Do the conversion inside your for loop: `TIMESTAMP = [str(datetime.datetime.strptime(i, ...).strftime(...)) for i in T]`

Comment: @Rakesh Yes I believe so, I am new to Python I could try this and see if this works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the other answers suggest, you require a different way, probably `map`. You may also use `pd.to_datetime()` and pass it the whole list. And then use the same as x-axis and the wind_speed for y-axis.

```
import pandas as pd    
timestamp = pd.to_datetime(T[1:])
```

It will create a DatetimeIndex which you can again format according to your needs, like:

```
timestamp = timestamp.strftime("%Y%m%d %I:%M:%S")
```

In one line:

```
timestamp = pd.to_datetime(T[1:]).strftime("%Y%m%d %I:%M:%S")
```

After having two lists for timestamp and wind_speed, use may use something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(13,6))
ax.plot(timestamp, wind_speed)
plt.xticks(rotation=30)
plt.show()
```

Comment: would it be possible to have a example of this? I new to Python and working with just that is slightly challenging

Comment: Thankvyou for your help. My date and time are now in the format "['20120101 01:00:00' '20120101 02:00:00' '20120101 03:00:00' ...
 '20131130", now how would I be able to plot this data against the wind_speed data posted in the original question?

Comment: Once you have both lists (timestamp and windspeed), you can use matplotlib to plot. Adding the code in the above answer.

Comment: I have attached the plotting function you updated, however,  the code does not generate a graph. the code remains on IN[*], any reason why this maybe?

Comment: It means it's in running state, one of the reason may be because you have 16k values. Try slicing first few values (timestamp[:100] and wind_speed[:100]) from both lists and then plot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173507/discussion-between-asif-khan-and-deepak-surana).

Comment: Thank you very much. All is resolved. Really appreciated your help!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173544/discussion-between-asif-khan-and-deepak-surana).

Answer (score 1):

This should help. Using `map` with lambda to convert datetime to your required format.

**Demo:**

```
import datetime
data = ['01/01/2012 01:00', '01/01/2012 02:00', '01/01/2012 03:00', '01/01/2012 04:00', '01/01/2012 05:00', '01/01/2012 06:00', '01/01/2012 07:00', '01/01/2012 08:00', '01/01/2012 09:00', '01/01/2012 10:00', '01/01/2012 11:00', '01/01/2012 12:00', '01/01/2012 13:00', '01/01/2012 14:00', '01/01/2012 15:00', '01/01/2012 16:00', '01/01/2012 17:00', '01/01/2012 18:00', '01/01/2012 19:00', '01/01/2012 20:00', '01/01/2012 21:00', '01/01/2012 22:00', '01/01/2012 23:00', '02/01/2012 00:00', '04/01/2012 23:00']
data = list(map(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x,  "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M").strftime("%Y%m%d %I:%M:%S"), data))
print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
['20120101 01:00:00', '20120101 02:00:00', '20120101 03:00:00', '20120101 04:00:00', '20120101 05:00:00', '20120101 06:00:00', '20120101 07:00:00', '20120101 08:00:00', '20120101 09:00:00', '20120101 10:00:00', '20120101 11:00:00', '20120101 12:00:00', '20120101 01:00:00', '20120101 02:00:00', '20120101 03:00:00', '20120101 04:00:00', '20120101 05:00:00', '20120101 06:00:00', '20120101 07:00:00', '20120101 08:00:00', '20120101 09:00:00', '20120101 10:00:00', '20120101 11:00:00', '20120201 12:00:00', '20120401 11:00:00']
```

Comment: In the second line named data, how would I include my entire column of data? The data I provided was a snippet of 16,000 values? Thank you

Comment: Do you mean `data = list(map(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x,  "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M").strftime("%Y%m%d %I:%M:%S"), T[1:]))
` ?

Comment: I have tried your code however, I am receiving the error "ValueError: time data '01/01/2012 02:00' does not match format 'd/%m/%Y %H:%M'" although I belive my format is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `T` is apparently a list of strings, not a string itself, so you need to iterate through T and pass the items in T to `strptime` instead.

```
for t in T:
    datetime.datetime.strptime(t, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S").strftime("%Y%m%d %I:%M:%S")
```